# Convert mysql field value from varchar to int and make comparison in query

Tags: mysql, type-conversion, field

i have a varchar field in the database that stores years in format like : 2004,2005,2006 etc... How can i convert the varchar format to int and put condition to it in  the where clause so i can get for example only years bigger than 2005  ?

I tried this

```
$sql = "select t1.* from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1._id = t2.id where t2.version='year' and t1.field='name' and COVERT(t1.value, UNSIGNED) > 2005";
```

But it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: If you are storing your dates as a delimited string (which is not recommended) you cannot directly interrogate it through MySQL, you will need to fetch the data and process with your prefered scripting language ie. PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `cast()`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1._id = t2.id
where t2.version='year'
and t1.field='name'
and CAST(t1.value AS UNSIGNED) > 2005
```

Also, you have `ep.value` in your query - I guessed you meant `t1`

Comment: yes that is what i ment and thank you, that work... i tried that also but dunno what i was mistaken because it did not work than but it does now. Nvm 10x for the help

Answer (score 0):

Mysql can compare strings with numbers

```
SELECT "2006" > 2005 -- answer is true
```

You you don't need a convert function. 
Maybe you need to provide more information?

Comment: The OP is storing delimited data (2004,2005,2006), this won't work.